# count occurrences of specific strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have a c++ project to count the LLOC of an input file, which is a file generated by a code generator consists of sequence of functions denoted F1( ), F2( ),..., Fn( ), followed by the main program and control structures like if, while, do, switch, and etc. we should count the number of: main program + functions + semicolons + equations + if statements + switch statements + while statements + for statements. I can easily count, for example, the number of ; using find function, but how can I count the number of functions? is there any way to count the substring F*( , which means every substring that starts with F and ends with ( ?

Here is my code to count the number of semicolons:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    ifstream testfile;
    std::string stringline;
    std::string str2(";");
    size_t found;
    int positioncount = 0;
    char arry[100];
    testfile.open("program.cpp");
    while (!testfile.eof()) {
        testfile.getline(arry, 50);
        stringline = arry;
        if (stringline.find(str2) != std::string::npos) {
            positioncount++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" << positioncount;
    testfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: parsing a language completely and correctly is not a simple task.

Comment: There are tools like *sloccount* that do this for you with considerably less effort than writing your own solution, which turns out not to be as easy as it looks.

Comment: since the code generated by the code generator has a specific format, I can easily find the occurrences of some substrings, but I do't know how to count the occurrences of substrings like F1(, F2(,...,Fn(

Comment: You can try std::regex.

Comment: This is a programming project, and I should write a program to count Logical Lines of Code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the code is machine generated you can probably make assumptions about it which make life much easier: for example no comments, no strings containing stuff that looks like code, no nested classes, etc.

That may let you get away with basic regular expressions plus counting braces. Modern C++ has built-in regular expressions, you may want to look into that for things like your function names.

Counting occurences is commonly done with maps (cf. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/?kw=map).